# How to show the selected option after selecting the option

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a form with table structure html like below:

```
                             <tr>
<td>Quotation Category<span class="required" style="color: red">*</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">
        <select name="quotation_category" class="form-control" style="width: 80%;" id="quotation_category">
            <option value="">Pilih Kategori</option>
            <option value="konvensional">Konvensional</option>
            <option value="syariah">Syariah</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="ujroh-style">Ujroh<span class="required" style="color: red">*</span>
</td>
<td class="ujroh-style">
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ujroh" name="ujroh">
    </div>
</td> </tr>
```

Below is my js:

```
document.querySelector('#quotation_category').addEventListener('change', () => {
        const select_value = document.querySelector('#quotation_category').value
        if (select_value === "konvensional") {
            document.getElementsByClassName('.ujroh-style').style.display = "none"
        } else if (select_value === "syariah") {
            document.getElementsByClassName('.ujroh-style').style.display = "revert"
        }
    })
```

I want, if I choose 'konvensional', that that selected option Ujroh will appear. If I choose 'syariah', then the selected option Ujroh dissapears. How to do that?

**INFORMATION**
My code gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display')
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems:

1. you are trying to get the `style` property from a collection of elements, and a collection of elements does not have the `style` property. Only a single element has a style property. Thankfully, you can iterate through each element
2. you are trying to get all elements of a particular class, with a string that has the `.` on it, which will get you an empty collection. Remove the `.`
3. `revert` is not a valid CSS `display` property enum. Use something else

So your previous JavaScript code would now be:

```
document.querySelector('#quotation_category').addEventListener('change', () => {
    const select_value = document.querySelector('#quotation_category').value
    if (select_value === "konvensional") {
        for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName('ujroh-style')) {
            el.style.display = "none"
        }
    } else if (select_value === "syariah") {
        for (const el of document.getElementsByClassName('ujroh-style')) {
            el.style.display = "inline-block"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of line is causing error

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.ujroh-style').style.display = "some-value"
```

1. You don't need to use `.` in front because you are already selecting by className
2. You are using getElements note the `s` it's plural if that's your intention
   you need to loop through all the elements and change the display property on the element not on the array

```
const elems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('ujroh-style'))
elems.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'your-value')
```

Comment: How to add if else logic from this result. if value 'konvensional' select option ujroh will dissapear and if I choose syariah, select option ujroh will appear??

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you use `'.classname'` as selector in the `getElementsByClassName` selector. And second you are trying to add a style to a collection of elements, that is not possible. To fix this, you have to add the display style to every element in the collection.

```js
document.querySelector('#quotation_category').addEventListener('change', () => {
  const select_value = document.querySelector('#quotation_category').value
  if (select_value === "konvensional") {
    document.querySelectorAll('.ujroh-style').forEach(x => x.style.display = 'none');
  } else if (select_value === "syariah") {
    document.querySelectorAll('.ujroh-style').forEach(x => x.style.display = 'inline-block');
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Quotation Category<span class="required" style="color: red">*</span></td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group col-md-9">
          <select name="quotation_category" class="form-control" style="width: 80%;" id="quotation_category">
              <option value="">Pilih Kategori</option>
              <option value="konvensional">Konvensional</option>
              <option value="syariah">Syariah</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="ujroh-style">Ujroh<span class="required" style="color: red">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="ujroh-style">
      <div class="form-group col-md-9">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ujroh" name="ujroh">
      </div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```